Как вернуть предыдущий код при условии Python
import random
import os
import chime
import win10toast

wins = 0
notwins = 0
balance = int(500)

a = "a"
while a == a:
    num = random.randint(20, 200)
    num2 = random.randint(20,200)

    print("──────────────────────────────────────────────────────Статистика────────────────────────────────────────────────────────")
    print(f"Баланс: {balance} рублей\n")
    print(f"Победы: {wins}")
    print(f"Поражения: {notwins}")
    print("───────────────────────────────────────────────────────Игра─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────")
    stavka = int(input("Сделайте ставку: "))
    vigrish = stavka * 2
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    if stavka > balance:
        chime.warning()
        toaster = win10toast.ToastNotifier()
        toaster.show_toast("Ошибка", "НЕдостаточно средств на счету")
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        
    if stavka == stavka:
        balance = balance - stavka
    print("──────────────────────────────────────────────────────Ставка────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────")
    print(f"Ваша ставка: {stavka} рублей")
    print("──────────────────────────────────────────────────────Игра──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────")
    print(f"Ваше число: {num2}")
    bim = input("Больше или меньше? b/m: ")
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print("─────────────────────────────────────────────────Результаты Игры────────────────────────────────────────────────────────")
    if bim == "b":
        if num > num2:
            chime.success()
            print(f"Вам выпало число {num}")
            print(f"Ваша ставка: {stavka} рублей")
            print(f"Ваш выигрыш: {vigrish} рублей")
            print("ВЫ ПОБЕДИЛИ")
            wins = wins + 1
            balance = balance + vigrish


        if num < num2:
            chime.warning()
            print(f"Вам выпало число {num}")
            print(f"Ваша ставка: {stavka} рублей")
            print(f"Ваш проигрыш: {stavka} рублей")
            print("ВЫ ПРОИГРАЛИ")
            notwins = notwins + 1


    if bim == "m":
        if num < num2:
            chime.success()
            print(f"Вам выпало число {num}")
            print(f"Ваша ставка: {stavka} рублей")
            print(f"Ваш выигрыш: {vigrish} рублей")
            print("ВЫ ПОБЕДИЛИ")
            wins = wins + 1
            balance = balance + vigrish

        if num > num2:
            chime.warning()
            print(f"Вам выпало число {num}")
            print(f"Ваша ставка: {stavka} рублей")
            print(f"Ваш проигрыш: {stavka} рублей")
            print("ВЫ ПРОИГРАЛИ")
            notwins = notwins + 1

    if bim == "add money":
        bablo = int(input("Скок бабла то надо?: "))
        balance = balance + bablo
        balance = balance + stavka
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')




    if bim == "break":
        break
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

Я хочу вернуть предыдущий код при условии что на счету будет недостаточно средств в этом участке кода
    if stavka > balance:
        chime.warning()
        toaster = win10toast.ToastNotifier()
        toaster.show_toast("Ошибка", "НЕдостаточно средств на счету")
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')


Попробуй для начала поискать на сайте. Тут примерно 100500 похожих вопросов.

Может я не понял вопрос, попробуй continue. Цикл вернётся к началу.
if stavka > balance:
    chime.warning()
    toaster = win10toast.ToastNotifier()
    toaster.show_toast("Ошибка", "НЕдостаточно средств на счету")
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    continue

